# Data bind into GridView on specific User Login details

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I am a Newbie in .NET development. I was assigned a task to bind the user related data into a grid view on user login. I have two web pages, one of which contains Login and authentication information. When user was redirected to second page, I need to provide a GridView control where user details should be automatically updated in grid view control in the background.

I have three different fields which were saved in sql table. particular user details need to be retrieved from the sql table on user login and bind the data to grid view automatically.

I have posted this query a couple of times, but didn't get any response.

Comment: Please provide code C# and SQL so this can get answered

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
  SqlConnection conobj;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conobj = new SqlConnection();
        string connestring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YOURCONNECTIONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
        conobj.ConnectionString = connestring;


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conobj;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from YOURTABLE";
         conobj.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

         conobj.Close();
    }
```